# Why does the ggplot legend show both line colour and linetype?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want the legend to show a blue solid line for "Panel regression", and a grey dashed line for "y = x". Why does it show the diagonal dashed lines in the legend?

```
 ggplot(df_REM24, aes(x=lngini_eurostat, y=fit_augment)) + 
  geom_point(size=1.5, shape=16, alpha=1) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula = y ~ x, aes(colour="blue")) +
  geom_abline(linetype = 2, aes(slope = 1, intercept = 0, colour="red")) + 
  labs(x="Observed ln(Gini)", y="Predicted ln(Gini)") + 
  theme_few() + 
  scale_colour_manual(name='Legend',
                      labels = c("Panel regression", "y = x"), 
                      values = c("#0072c3", "#737373")) + 
  theme(legend.position = c(.15, .9), 
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black", size=0.3), 
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

Also, I set the legend.key fill to white but it remains in grey.

[image: the plot I currently have]

Comment: Please share some data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Answer (score 2):

First you should set `show.legend = FALSE` in your `geom_abline`. After that you can use this code to set white background in your boxes in the legend:  `guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA)), linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA)))` . You can use the following code (ps I created random data):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
ggplot(df_REM24, aes(x=lngini_eurostat, y=fit_augment)) + 
  geom_point(size=1.5, shape=16, alpha=1) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula = y ~ x, aes(colour="blue")) +
  geom_abline(linetype = 2, aes(slope = 1, intercept = 0, colour="red"), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  labs(x="Observed ln(Gini)", y="Predicted ln(Gini)") + 
  theme_few() + 
  scale_colour_manual(name='Legend',
                      labels = c("Panel regression", "y = x"), 
                      values = c("#0072c3", "#737373")) + 
  theme(legend.position = c(.15, .9), 
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black", size=0.3), 
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA)), linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA)))
```

Output:

[image]

##### Data

```
df_REM24 <- data.frame(lngini_eurostat = sort(runif(10, 3, 4)),
                       fit_augment = sort(runif(10, 3, 4)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to make the grey line in the legend "dashed" instead of "solid"?

Answer (score 1):

Should work with the missing bracket and without the `aes` in geom_smooth per this reproducible example with made-up data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(x = rep(seq(2, 16, 1), 2),
       y = abs(rnorm(30, 10, 10)),
       colour = rep(c("fore", "hind"), 15)
) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, colour = colour)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(colour = "blue") +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"))
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>